# Hypothesis testing for RMSE

Tags: hypothesis-testing, rms

I want to compare two distributions of values. While the mean value is approximatively the same in both distributions, the RMSE in both with respect to 1 is quite different.

With RMSE I mean $\sqrt{(((1−)^2)}$, with VCF the Volume Conservation Factor 
[image]

However, the RMSE does not have any estimate of uncertainty. I was wondering if there was any statistical method with which I can obtain a p-value testing the hypothesis that the RMSE are equal.

One thing I thought of doing was to segment the distribution into subsections, and create a distribution of RMSEs. Which is not very clean and can be optimized to obtain desired values.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you mean by "RMSE" (I know, "root mean squared error," but what is the "error" in these examples?) and what "with respect to 1" is referring to?  If you want to apply statistical methods then, at a minimum, you will need to account for how many data are being displayed in each plot. You likely will also want to consider how these data were collected and measured.

Comment: @whuber with RMSE I mean $\sqrt{(mean((1-VCF)^2)}$, with VCF the Volume Conservation Factor

Comment: That is an unusual definition of "RMSE": it's important that you explain that in your post.

Comment: So comparing means is not appropriate, comparing distributions then?

Comment: How about a hypothesis test that compares the variance of the two samples?

Comment: What I did now is to compute a Wilcoxon signed-rank test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) on the |1 - VCF| distributions